# Sql cambia los formatos de numeros float ingresados desde c#

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

Hola comunidad espero me puedan ayudar con este problema ya que no se a que se deba de antemano gracias por su ayuda.

Tengo una columna de mi tabla en sql Server de tipo float y mi proyecto en tres capas, también uso ajax de jquery para enviar los datos.

En el momento en que envio  el numero de tipo flotante por ejemplo 12.10 desde javascript al final en sql server termina reflejado como 1,210.00.

¿Alguien sabe a que se deba esto?.

Mi código no marca ningún error y al colocarle un punto de interrupcion el resultado enviado viaja como 12.10 solo en el sql server me lo inserta como 1,210.00

Al ejecutar esta consulta en sql server obtengo el resultado de abajo. ¿Alguien sabe como cambiarlo a Español-Mexico sin desinstalar sql server?

```
SELECT @@LANGUAGE AS 'Language Name'; 

-----  Resultado de consulta   
Language Name                   
------------------------------  
us_english
```

Codigo ajax

```js
  var id_fila = $("#gvDatosBI2").jqxGrid('getrowdata', row);
                        
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            datatype: "json",
                            url: "frmActualizar.aspx/Actualizar_Persona_Datos",
                            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    
                            data: '{id_persona:"' + id_fila.id_Persona + '",Total_pago:"' + parseFloat($("#txtTotal").val()) + '"}',
                           
                            cache: false,

                            success: function(data, status, xhr) {
                                // update command is executed.
                               
                                commit(true);


                            },
                            error: function(error) {
                                alert(error.responseText);
                                console.log(error.responseText);
                                jsonValue = jQuery.parseJSON(Error.responseText);
                                alert(error.respose.Text);
                                alert("Error");
                            }
                        });
```

Codigo del web Method

```
[WebMethod]      
    public static void Actualizar_Persona_Datos(int id_persona, float Total_pago)
    {
        Transacciones t = new Transacciones();           
        t.Actualizar_Persona(id_persona, Total_pago);           

    }
```

Codigo lógica de negocio

```
 public void Actualizar_Persona(int id_persona, float Total_pago)
    {

        conexion.Actualiza_Persona(id_persona, Total_pago);

    }
```

Codigo Acceso a Datos

```
 public void Actualiza_Persona(int id_persona, float Total_pago)
    {

        SqlParameter[] sqlparameter =
        {
            new SqlParameter ("@Id_persona",SqlDbType.Int),
            new SqlParameter ("@Total_Pago", SqlDbType.Float)

        };

        sqlparameter[0].Value = id_persona;
        sqlparameter[1].Value = Total_pago;

        _conexion.Actualizar_Datos("Actualizar_Datos",sqlparameter);


    }
```

Comment: Hola @MiguelZarate en ajax lo paso asi: data: '{id_persona:"' + id_fila.id_Persona + '",Total_pago:"' + parseFloat($("#txtTotal").val()) ... y en mis demas metodos los paso como variables de tipo float.

Comment: y puedes agregar esas secciones de codigo en tu pregunta?

Comment: Hola @MiguelZarate ya he colocado el codigo espero me puedas ayudar gracias.

Comment: Si `Total_pago` es un numero, porque en el ajax lo pasa como cadena. Por defecto .net tratara de castiar el valor a float. adicional no muestras el procedimiento de Actualizar_Datos, espero que tampoco dentro de float lo pases a cadena.

Comment: Siempre trata de armar el objeto y luego convertirlo a cadena asi: `data: JSON.stringify({id_persona: id_fila.id_Persona, Total_pago: parseFloat($("#txtTotal").val())})` de esta forma siempre evitaras dolores de cabeza con la concatenacion de cadena.

Comment: Por cierto, podrias colocar como es `Actualizar_Datos` por dentro?. Puede que el problema este dentro de Actualizar_Datos

Comment: Hola @OrlandoDeLaRosa gracias por tus recomendaciones las tomare en cuanta y gracias por tu ayuda sin embargo ya arregle mi problema era la configuracion de idioma de sql server como lo mencione arriba de cualquier forma gracias.

Comment: Que bien que hayas solucionado el problema

Comment: Si solucionaste el problema, por favor agrega una respuesta que explique el problema y como fue que lo solucionaste